# Type of layer mask to make underneath layers transparent?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, mask, effects

I have a design where I'd like to make:

- the white rectangle layer makes all layers beneath it transparent (you can see the pink)
- the stroke around the letters makes all layers beneath it transparent (see pink)
- The extruded 3D portion of the letters makes all layers beneath it transparent (see pink)

Is there a type of layer mask setting or clipping mask I can use to achieve this? So that I dont need to add a layer mask to a group of all the layers beneath it?

[image]

Comment: Hi. You will need to use groups, and put the mask on the group. There's really no other way.  However, to be honest I don't think Photoshop is the right kind of software for work like this. It would be better to use vector software such as Adobe Illustrator, then you wouldn't technically need to use any masks at all, as you can do proper boolean operations or use the Shape Builder to make all the pieces of a logo.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yeah, I couldn't break my head long enough to find a way to do this without a mask applied to a group. I guess what I'm asking is a type of layer where the pixels on it make everything else behind it transparent. Sort of like a live mask.